# Unable to connect to internet from EC2 Private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I created a new EC2 instance inside a working VPC. We use bastion to connect to the private network. The problem is, once connected (through ssh), i cannot download any package or install anything because the instance seems to be closed to the internet.

These are the rules configured in the instance's Security Groups:

inbound -

[image]

outbound -

[image]

Commands like git clone repo or apt-get update timeout. A ping to google returns nothing.

Comment: You need a NAT.

Comment: Either your instance needs a public IP, or your VPC needs a NAT Gateway.

Comment: thanks @JakubKania and Mark B. I happen to have a NAT created but not assigned to this instance. Is it possible to change the instance's subnet?

Comment: @ntonnelier Yes, but this is really not a place to discuss it. This question belongs on serverfault and it's probably a duplicate over there.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted to be fair, it's a legitimate question regardless of whether it's in the right place or not.